# Fail to compare string using in_array()

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my code :

```
<?php



$states = array();
if (($file = fopen("branch.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($state = fgets($file)) !== FALSE) {
         $states[] = $state;
    }
    fclose($file);  
}
print_r($states);


$searchkeyword = "FLORIDA";
if(in_array($searchkeyword, $states)){
    echo "we found " . $searchkeyword  . "\n";
} else {
    echo "we can't found " . $searchkeyword  . "\n";
}
?>
```

This is the result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => FLORIDA

    [1] => CHICAGO
)
we can't found FLORIDA
```

Everything looks ok to me, I can see the first element of the array is FLORIDA, but in_array() fails to find FLORIDA. I probably have missed something.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://3v4l.org/5KaCU)

Comment: @JohnConde Have you tried to fetch from .csv file?

Comment: Maybe there is invisible whitespace in the file? Try `$states[] = trim($state);`, or `$states[] = "={$state}=";` to get a visual indication.

Comment: Please show us a `var_dump($states);`

Comment: @GregSchmidt trim($state) solves this problem, It's kind of weird though, I checked the .cvs files, the word FLORIDA doesn't have any whitespace (front and end), but when I run var_dump($states) shows that FLORIDA has 9 characters.

Comment: @RiggsFolly's `var_dump` suggestion is better than mine. :-)

Comment: You can use something like https://3v4l.org/r7Mvo to see what the char is. Assuming it is in ascii. Can use http://www.asciitable.com/ to map the integer to character since it likely is a control character (before 32).